# Arduino call windows/system left/right arrow function

Tags: windows, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm new to the Arduino scene and was wondering how I would get my sketch to call or interface with windows. For instance if I create a circuit with two buttons how would I use those buttons to call the left and right windows functions?

Is this even possible?(of course it is, its Arduino but how?!)

Thanks in advance. If anyone wants to see my sketch or anything just ask :/ its nothing exciting. plus I'm not sure it will really be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for anything similar I found the necessary tutorials and libraries here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard